# iPhone alarm goes quiet when I touch it

Tags: iphone

Is this a problem or new feature on iPhone that is used to detect when the user has awakened? Anyway I want to disable it because sometimes I touch it when only partially awake, and climb back into bed.

I use iPhone 11 pro Max and always updated to latest operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the Attention Aware features of iOS, introduced with iPhone X: [Turn Attention Aware features on or off on your iPhone or iPad Pro](https://support.apple.com/102216)

> - If you're looking at your device, it will lower the volume sound of your alerts.

> If you don’t want to use these features, open the Settings app, tap Face ID & Passcode, then turn off Attention Aware Features.

Comment: Looks like your link is wrong/dead.

Comment: @agarza Thanks fixed

Comment: Thank you for your help